# Error when executing Cacti poller.php

Tags: php, linux, cacti

I have installed Cacti, and when I run poller.php, it gives me following error:

```
sh: /rrdtool: No such file or directory
```

I have tracked it to the following bit of code:

```
$command = '/usr/bin/rrdtool' . " - ";

$rrd_struc["fd"] = popen($command, "w");
```

what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon this, check if your safe_mode is turned off.